# MySQL Reader in C# - "There is already an open Data Reader associated with this connection which must be closed first."

Tags: c#, mysql, multithreading

I have a problem with my MySQL Reader - I am running the reader in a loop, checking if a configured entry exists in my database. After the reader is applied, the reader is getting closed and set to null again.
Anyhow, I always get this error message when I am running the "CheckExistEntry" - function in my code.

"07.04.2021 14:28:05    ERROR: There is already an open Data Reader associated with this connection which must be closed first."

The error does not occur in the following situations:

If I set a breakpoint at the relevant position in the code, the error does not occur.
If I set a sleep for 1000 MS before the reader is executed, the error does not occur.

Is it possible that C# is running loops via multithreading without me knowing it?

Here's the code:

```cs
public bool CheckExistEntry(string iColumnName)
{
    MySqlDataReader reader = null;
    string query2 = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM defectdetection.defects_main";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query2, MySqlConn);
    try
    {
        // SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA =[Database Name] AND TABLE_NAME =[Table Name];#
        // write_Log()
        write_Log(log_directory, log_file, "BEFORE ExecuteReader");
        //COMMENT FOR STACKOVERFLOW: cmd.ExecuteReader() triggers the Error.
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        write_Log(log_directory, log_file, "AFTER ExecuteReader");
        //now, communication with MySQL is finished. .. 
        List<string> ColumnNames = new List<string>();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            ColumnNames.Add((string)reader[0]);
        }
        if (ColumnNames.Contains(iColumnName))
        {
            reader.Close();
            reader.Dispose();
            reader = null;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            reader.Close();
            reader.Dispose();
            reader = null;
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (reader != null)
        {
            reader.Close();
            reader.Dispose();
            reader = null;
        }
              
        exception = new ArgumentException(ex.Message);
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        //TODO handle exception
                
        write_Log(log_directory, log_file,"ERROR: There is already an open Data Reader associated with this connection which must be closed first.");
                
        progressBarForm.Invoke(new updatebar(progressBarForm.Close));
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

i tried it with a triple-using statement now (using MySqlConnection, using MySqlCommand, using MySqlDatareader). But it still does not work, i get another error now: "Connection must be valid and open."

```
                using (MySqlConnection MySqlConnLocal = new MySqlConnection()) {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query2, MySqlConnLocal)) {
            using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {

                
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    ColumnNames.Add((string)reader[0]);
                }
            }

            if (ColumnNames.Contains(iColumnName))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
            }
            }
```

Comment: What is `MySqlConn`, and what else might have access to it? Note: you're making your life *very* hard with that cleanup code: simply `using var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();` would do everything correctly, no matter how the code exits. However, the key thing here is "does *another* bit of code not clean up *their* reader?" - it could be that you're blocked behind them, and possibly being saved by a GC when you add the breakpoint

Comment: *Don't* reuse DbConnection objects. There's no benefit, and a *lot* of disadvantages. Connectionos aren't thread safe *and* any locks taken remain active until the connection closes. This can easily lead to deadlocks or block the entire system. There's a reason all tutorials and documents show connections created inside `using` blocks. Connection pooling means that creating a new connection and closing as soon as possible doesn't cost anything

Comment: This code could be simplified a *lot* with `using`, `async/await` and the `Progress` class. *All* of the code that tries to dispose and close connections and readers can be removed.  If you use `ExecuteReaderAsync` you won't need to use an extra thread. And if you use `Progress<>` you won't have to use the hard-coded *blocking* call to `progressBarForm.Invoke`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't dispose of "cmd". Try the following:

```
                   ...

public bool CheckExistEntry(string iColumnName)
{
    string query2 = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM defectdetection.defects_main";
    
    try
    {
        using (MySqlConnection mySqlConn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionStr))
        {
            mySqlConn.Open();

            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query2, mySqlConn))
            {
                using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        if ((string)reader[0] == iColumnName)
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var exception = new ArgumentException(ex.Message);
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        //TODO handle exception

        write_Log(log_directory, log_file, "ERROR: There is already an open Data Reader associated with this connection which must be closed first.");

        //ToDo: add any additional desired code
        
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I tried it now, with triple "using" - statement , but i get a new error now : "Connection must be valid and open".

Answer (score 0):

FIXED IT NOW: This Code here was the solution:

```
                //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
            using (MySqlConnection MySqlConnLocal = new MySqlConnection(ConnString))
            {
                MySqlConnLocal.Open();
                using (MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(query2, MySqlConnLocal))
                {

                    reader = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {


                        ColumnNames.Add((string)reader[0]);

                    }
                }
            }
```